# Flutter- Firebase- The method '[]' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy intentando recoger un dato de Firebase.  Uso un FutureBuilder para mostrar el texto en la pantalla pero me lanza una excepción que, según entiendo, significa que ese dato no existe.

Tengo escrito un código similar que funciona bien, por eso no entiendo que puede estar pasando aquí.

Este es el código qué me da el error:

```
  Container(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: Firestore.instance
                    .collection('messagges')
                    .document(
                        'T1am0ZAf4INduPGfjefWzAPZqON2-AuQbpeON9bZpLP0IPbUbXBZZosD3')
                    .get(), //Hardcodeado para intentantar acotar el problema

                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot4) {
                  if (snapshot4.hasData) {
                    String aux = '';
                    if (snapshot4.data == null) {
                      print('snapshot4.data is null');
                    } else {
                      print('snapshot4.data  is not null');
                      if (snapshot4.hasError) {
                        print('Error snapshot4.hasError');
                      } else {
                        // Prints
                        aux = snapshot4.data['lastMessage']; //this throws an exception as if lastMessage didnt exist
                        print(aux);
                      }
                    }
                    return Text(aux);
                  } else
                    return Text('no Data');
                },
              ),
            ),
```

[image: La estructura de la base de datos]

I/flutter (11240): snapshot4.data  is not null

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState#258b9):
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling:

alguna idea?

Comment: Hello, we are at Stackoverflow in Spanish please edit your question by translating it so it can be accepted and answered ;)

Comment: Oops, no me había dado cuenta que estaba en español. Ya lo he traducido. He dejado el titulo con el mensaje original, ya que es un mensaje del compilador. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo a mi mismo.
El Nombre de la colección en firebase no es igual a cuándo lo llamo desde el código (message vs messagge).